# Spring: Task Executor service with datetime based queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-async

I want to implement a Executor service for Tasks which will start running after some time,
For example let's assume I have these tasks;

```
task1 = new Task(1,10)   //Task with id 1 and will start after 10 min   
task2 = new Task(2,15)   //Task with id 2 and will start after 15 min   
task3 = new Task(3,5)    //Task with id 3 and will start after 5 min   
task4 = new Task(4,30)   //Task with id 4 and will start after 30 min
```

when I submit all of those to an executor service, I should get the following result;

(after 5 min):
   ...task 3 is running...
(after 10 min)
   ...task 1 is running...
(after 15 min)
   ...task 2 is running...
(after 30 min)
   ...task 4 is running...

I could find out how can I implement this. Can you help me about it?

Comment: check out this link https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-task-scheduling-with-scheduled-annotation/

Comment: I don’t want them running in periodically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). Here's an example showing how to schedule a thread to run in 5 minutes.

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
Thread thread = new Thread();
executor.schedule(thread, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```